# Most efficient way to take many rows to one row

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a table where a plugin keeps all form submissions, in this table I have a row for each field like this:

```
1 'Name' 'Tony'
2 'Surname' 'Smith'
3 'Mail' 'tony@mail.com'
4 etc.
```

I want to take all this data to a table where all data is in columns, like this:

```
New_Id Name   Surname  Mail
     1 'Tony' 'Smith'  'tony@mail.com'
     2 'Mary' 'DotCom' 'mary@dotcom'
```

I have a A LOT of these records so efficiency is important. My first approach would be a PHP loop on every field in first table and then decide if I have to insert or update in the second table, this solution might even need a previous select to see if field is already populated so the solution is not very nice.

Can you think of a better solution?

**EDIT: This is my structure:**

This is my target table, field names are in Spanish but they are name, birth_date, adress, etc.

```
create table target_table
    (id     int not null AUTO_INCREMENT,
    blog_id     int,
    submission_id   int,
    form_id     varchar(250) character set utf8 collate utf8_general_ci,
    submission_date timestamp,
    ip      varchar(250) character set utf8 collate utf8_general_ci,
    sitio           varchar(250) character set utf8 collate utf8_general_ci,
    nombre      varchar(4000) character set utf8 collate utf8_general_ci,
    fecha_nacimiento varchar(250),
    email           varchar(250) character set utf8 collate utf8_general_ci,
    direccion       varchar(250) character set utf8 collate utf8_general_ci,
    cp          varchar(250) character set utf8 collate utf8_general_ci,
    PRIMARY KEY(id));
```

And source are actually two tables, cforms_submissions is parent with submission_id, submission_date and email:

```
id               int(11) unsigned PK
form_id          varchar(3)
sub_date         timestamp
email            varchar(40)
ip               varchar(15)
```

And cforms_data is child table with fields and their values:

```
f_id             int(11) unsigned PK
sub_id           int(11) unsigned <---- This is FK to parent
field_name       varchar(100)
field_val        text
```

So, I should do something like:

```
select submissions....
for each submission
    select fields in submissions
    for each field in submission
        if first_field
            insert
        else
            update
```

Maybe is there a better approach?

Thank you, BTW, I'm working with MySql

Comment: How are the current records linked? E.g. how do you know that `'Name' -> 'Tony'` is associated with `'Surname' -> 'Smith'`?

Comment: At least you're getting _out_ of using an EAV.  Knowing your current design will be helpful,,,

Comment: Are the list of form fields finite and already defined?  IE, the system or user can't add arbitrary new keys?

Comment: Are you looking for a solution that will allow you to initialize target_table one time? Maybe the plugin is being replaced? Or are you asking for a programmmatic solution to perform this task in an on going manner? If the former, I think I would start by normalizing cforms_submission and cforms_data.

Comment: jklemmack: Are the list of form fields finite and already defined? -> YES

Comment: Karl, I'm asking for a programmatic solution better than my approach, the table structure comes from a third party plugin so I can't modify it

Comment: Does every sub_id have values for all the fields in the table?

Comment: Chris Nash, I think we can assume yes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, I had misunderstood the question.
As long as the number of tables if finite you can do N joins in the following way:

```
INSERT_INTO target_table(blog_id, form_id, ....) 
SELECT id, ..., name_table.field_val, address_table, ... 
FROM cforms_data name_table INNER JOIN cforms_data address_table 
    ON  name_table.sub_id = address_table.sub_id 
    INNER JOIN cforms_data date_table ON name_table.sub_id = name_table.sub_id
    INNER JOIN ...
WHERE name_table.field_name = 'NAME' AND address_table.field_name = 'ADDRESS' AND...
```

What you are doing is for each field in the target getting the subset of entries that match that field in the source, and for those matching it with the field in the other subsets with the same ID.
The query is going to be painfully long since you'll have an alias per field, but the performance shouldn't be terrible on if it is properly indexed (probably on field_name,sub_id). I think you can add the field_name comparison in the form, but I am not sure if that is MySQL or only Oracle.
You probably need the parent for the email, but I that is trivial

**ORIGINAL:**

Just execute in MySql

> INSERT INTO target_table(blog_id, form_id....)   SELECT id, form_id,,
>   ...., ...  FROM cforms_submissions INNER JOIN cforms_data ON id ==
>   sub_id  HAVING MAX(sub_date)

I am assuming you want to insert the last record. Otherwise, vary the SELECT accordingly. The fields in the INSERT INTO have to match the ones in the SELECT.

Comment: Could you give more detail on the query? I think this is ok for the submission, but my concern is with **each** of the fields in cforms_data...

Comment: Every INNER JOIN line in the query deals with one named field in the target table, selecting just those fields that match by name and have the same submission ID as the parent. So for instance to get the `address`, you join the entire cforms_data table again, selecting those records with matching sub_id and field_name = 'ADDRESS'. If some of the fields are missing, you can use LEFT JOIN instead of INNER JOIN, and those fields will be null in the result.